# How to commit deleted files in cornerstone for mac?

Tags: svn, macos, cornerstone

I am a user of cornerstone. Asking this question twice via support email was not answered by them.

Just simply: How we commit deleted files?

Let say, we import a new project to svn then re checkout that project. After that we delete few files in local machine, and expect that we can commit those deleted files, so the files will also be deleted in svn server, so those file will also be deleted from our college when updating their source.

But so far, when I select those deleted files, the commit menu won't appear on right click(blurred). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to commit the *deletion* to the repository, not the *deleted files.*

I've never used Cornerstone, but I imagine there would be an option for doing an SVN delete rather than a normal delete.

This is analogous to command-line Subversion, where you need to do `svn delete` rather than just removing the file.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I would like to commit the deletion, so the deletion will be propagated to my team member. I knew its possible in command line, because when we delete file and commit, the deletion will be commited. But somehow i didn't find a way to do that with cornerstone.